# Default Configuration Files Hadoop Accelerator

Tags: gridgain

I just downloaded the Hadoop Accelerator from the gridgain.org website (gridgain-hadoop-os-6.2.0-nix.zip).  When looking at the documentation that is located at http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Hadoop+Accelerator+Installation, it mentions the following in the "Configuring GGFS" section:

---

Configuration files for GGFS client and data nodes are located in GridGain config folder:
•config/ggfs/default-ggfs-base.xml - contains common configuration for GGFS client and data nodes
•config/ggfs/default-ggfs-client.xml - contains configuration for GGFS client nodes
•config/ggfs/default-config.xml - contains configuration for GGFS data nodes

You can get started with default configuration and then change individual properties as you progress.

---

The config directory only contains the default-config.xml.

Where can I get the other 2 files or example configs?

Thanks,

Keith

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded installation should have a "docs/hadoop_readme.pdf" file with up-to-date installation instructions. The instructions on the Wiki will be updated soon.